# Retrieving multiple items and displaying them on a website

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to retrieve multiple records from a django database to display in a table on a webpage.

This is my code so far...

```
class AdminView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'admin.html'
print("hello world")
def get(self, request):
    template = 'admin.html'
    data = str(Quiz.objects.all())
    admin = AdminForm(request.GET)
    context = {"admin": admin}
    context['data'] = data
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This is the webpage so far...

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated%}
{% if request.user.username  == "teacher"  %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Admin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}

    Admin Test

    {{ data }}

    </body>
    </html>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
<h2>Login Required</h2>
{% endif %}
```

What do you think is wrong with this code? How can I get it to display str?

Comment: What *is* wrong with this code?

Comment: Exactly what is wrong with this code.

Comment: [so] is for help solving problems, not to guess what they are, you should describe the issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve multiple records from a django database to display in a table on a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some odd reason you're trying to get the string representation of a queryset

```
data = str(Quiz.objects.all())
```

you don't need to, just set data to the queryset

```
data = Quiz.objects.all()
```

Then just iterate over them

```
{% for obj in data %}
    {{ obj }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This still just outputs: 
Admin Test Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object Quiz object - to the webpage.

Comment: @PhilipCrocker - Yes it will, `obj` here is an instance of your quiz object so you need to decide what part of that object you want to display

Comment: This is what this code outputted. What syntax should I use to display a specific part of the object.

Comment: @PhilipCrocker - The same type of syntax you used to check the username of a user.

Comment: Do you mean request.quiz.username?

Comment: Thank you this answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Sayse answered you could, for example, do something like:

```
{% for obj in data %}
    {{ obj.display }}
{% endfor %}
```

Your Quiz model might be something like:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):

    ...

    def display(self):
        return 'This will display on your page'
```